# Error while setting the DenyAddAndCustomizePages property of tenant site using PnP Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I am trying to set DenyAddAndCustomizePages property of my tenant site using the script below but it gives an error. What should be the alternative for using it with new PnP.Powershell module?  Our project was running for several months with **SharepointPnPPowershell**  But as this is now deprecated and not supported anymore, after installing PnP. Powershell we are seeing lots of issues.

***Method invocation failed because [PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Model.SPOSite] does not contain a method named 'update'.***

I tried to include ***Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell -Scope "Local"*** as described at the end of the article below but that did not work.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/258967/problems-with-update-method-to-change-conditional.html

```
$site = Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed -Url $Url
$site.DenyAddAndCustomizePages = "Disabled"
$site.Update() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Can we have both PnP.Powershell and SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline  modules installed at the same time as per the answer in the article below?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/258967/problems-with-update-method-to-change-conditional.html

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you found the answer by now? If not, have you tried this?

```
Set-PnpTenantSite -Identity $siteUrl -DenyAddAndCustomizePages:$false | Out-Null
```

Tks.

Alex